# can't change background colour in base web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, baseweb

i am using next js in my project and when i create a button to change colour they only change the base web components colour not background colour.

### _app.tsx

```js
import '../styles/globals.css';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { Provider as StyletronProvider } from 'styletron-react';
import { LightTheme, BaseProvider, ThemeProvider, DarkTheme } from 'baseui';
import { styletron } from '../helpers/styletron';
import { useState } from 'react';

const THEME = {
    light: 'light',
    dark: 'dark',
};

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(THEME.light);
    return (
        <StyletronProvider value={styletron}>
            <BaseProvider
                theme={theme === THEME.light ? LightTheme : DarkTheme}
            >
                <Component
                    {...pageProps}
                    THEMES={THEME}
                    theme={theme}
                    settheme={setTheme}
                />
            </BaseProvider>
        </StyletronProvider>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

### index.tsx

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

interface props {
    THEMES: {
        light: string;
        dark: string;
    };
    settheme: any;
    theme: any;
}

const Home: NextPage<props> = ({ THEMES, settheme, theme }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <button
                onClick={() =>
                    settheme(theme === THEMES.dark ? THEMES.light : THEMES.dark)
                }
            >
                change
            </button>
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

and when i click on button it not change the background colour to black

[image: poc]

like you see above it not change the background

Comment: Try adding `console.log(theme)` in MyApp component, to see if the state is getting updated

Comment: it's changing  i don't known what the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't known it's the best way of doing it but it's work

what i do is add a class in html tag called theme which indicate the current theme which user select and store that theme name in localstorage and using css to add background colour according to html class name

if anyone has better solution pls don't hesitate to share.

### _app.tsx

```js
import '../styles/globals.css';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { Provider as StyletronProvider } from 'styletron-react';
import { LightTheme, BaseProvider, DarkTheme } from 'baseui';
import { styletron } from '../helpers/styletron';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const THEME = {
    light: 'light',
    dark: 'dark',
};

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState<string>('');
    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            !localStorage.getItem('theme')
                ? localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark')
                : '';
            let user_themes = localStorage.getItem('theme');
            document
                .getElementById('theme')
                ?.classList?.add(user_themes || theme);
            setTheme(user_themes || theme);
        }
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (theme) {
            document
                .getElementById('theme')
                ?.classList?.remove(
                    theme === THEME.dark ? THEME.light : THEME.dark
                );
            document.getElementById('theme')?.classList?.add(theme);
            localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
        }
    }, [theme]);
    return (
        <StyletronProvider value={styletron}>
            <BaseProvider
                theme={theme === THEME.light ? LightTheme : DarkTheme}
            >
                <Component
                    {...pageProps}
                    THEMES={THEME}
                    theme={theme}
                    settheme={setTheme}
                />
            </BaseProvider>
        </StyletronProvider>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

### _document.tsx

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

export default class CustomDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html id='theme'>
                <Head />
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}
```

### index.tsx

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

interface props {
    THEMES: {
        light: string;
        dark: string;
    };
    settheme: any;
    theme: any;
}

const Home: NextPage<props> = ({ THEMES, settheme, theme }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <button
                onClick={() =>
                    settheme(theme === THEMES.dark ? THEMES.light : THEMES.dark)
                }
            >
                change
            </button>
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

### globals.css

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html.dark {
    background: rgba(12, 12, 12);
}

html.light {
    background: rgb(252, 252, 252);
}
```